# django-q qcluster starts and exits while running in Pycharm Debug

Tags: django, pycharm, python-3.7, django-q

I'm running a Django project with [django-q](https://django-q.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) in PyCharm. `manage.py runserver` is running in one instance, and `manage.py qcluster` is running in another. `qcluster` starts up fine, then immediately exits gracefully. Here is the full text:

```
/Users/user/PycharmProjects/project/venv/bin/python /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 65362 --file /Users/user/PycharmProjects/project/manage.py qcluster --settings=project.settings.dev
Connected to pydev debugger (build 193.6494.30)
pydev debugger: process 21339 is connecting

16:03:44 [Q] INFO Q Cluster grey-kentucky-georgia-avocado starting.
16:03:44 [Q] INFO Process-1 guarding cluster grey-kentucky-georgia-avocado
16:03:44 [Q] INFO Q Cluster grey-kentucky-georgia-avocado running.
16:03:44 [Q] INFO Process-1:1 ready for work at 21343
16:03:44 [Q] INFO Process-1:2 ready for work at 21344
16:03:44 [Q] INFO Process-1:3 ready for work at 21345
16:03:44 [Q] INFO Process-1:4 ready for work at 21346
16:03:44 [Q] INFO Process-1:5 ready for work at 21347
16:03:44 [Q] INFO Process-1:6 monitoring at 21348
16:03:44 [Q] INFO Process-1:7 pushing tasks at 21349
16:03:44 [Q] INFO Q Cluster grey-kentucky-georgia-avocado stopping.
16:03:44 [Q] INFO Process-1 stopping cluster processes
16:03:45 [Q] INFO Process-1:7 stopped pushing tasks
16:03:46 [Q] INFO Process-1:1 stopped doing work
16:03:46 [Q] INFO Process-1:2 stopped doing work
16:03:46 [Q] INFO Process-1:3 stopped doing work
16:03:46 [Q] INFO Process-1:4 stopped doing work
16:03:46 [Q] INFO Process-1:5 stopped doing work
16:03:47 [Q] INFO Process-1 waiting for the monitor.
16:03:47 [Q] INFO Process-1:6 stopped monitoring results
16:03:47 [Q] INFO Q Cluster grey-kentucky-georgia-avocado has stopped.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Obviously I would like it to stay running indefinitely. If I run it from PyCharm's `manage.py` terminal it operates as expected. `manage.py runserver` runs as expected.

My versions:

- Python 3.7
- Django 3.0.3
- django-q 1.2.1
- PyCharm 2019.3.3 Pro

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To run django_q in PyCharm Debug, I had to open Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Python Debugger, and select `Gevent compatible`. I found the solution from this issue: https://github.com/Koed00/django-q/issues/367.

Comment: Problem occurs for VS Code as well. Solution is to add `"gevent": true` to launch configuration for qcluster.